# How to fix "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content in Magento

Tags: php, apache, magento, optimization

I have minified js and css and optimized images. Used async="async" in
js where it is applicable. How to fix "Eliminate render-blocking
JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content"

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Render means loading, so if something is render-blocking, it means
>   that it is keeping the page from loading as quickly as it could.
>
> 1) load css in the headers but Js in the footer
>
> 2) Use sprite images
>
> 3) You can add htaccess code for for better performance
>
> - Gzip compression
> - set Expires and Cache-Control headers
> - Browser cache-control
>
> 4) Load only required css/js on pages
>
> Choose Best Method Once you’ve identified which scripts need to be
>   moved it is time to decide “how” to fix them. There are two main
>   methods to choose from. The first is to make the scripts inlined; in
>   this method the contents of the script are added directly into the
>   HTML of the page and are only loaded once they are needed. This is the
>   best option if the script is small and applies to a single page.
>
> Another option is to defer the script. When you defer JavaScript you
>   are delaying any non-essential scripts from loading until after the
>   first render or until after the more essential portions have loaded.
>   This method is best when the script is not crucial and can wait to
>   load.
>
> PS:- We can not resolve this fully in some cases.
>
> I Hope it's helpful for you

Comment: Thank you for very clean explain,can i use any other third party extension for same issue? @Umesh

Comment: Yes, there are many extension have,you can try this one,it will definitely good result and impact your website speed :- https://amasty.com/magento-google-page-speed-optimizer.html

Comment: Yogesh, did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript won't block DOM elements from loading if you've used the `async` attribute. But we're only half way there. Regarding CSS, minifying it is a good start, but it will still block the parser from rendering elements until it's finished loading. The following is the solution that I prefer, which adjusts the `media` attribute of a stylesheet link until it's loaded:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" media="wait" onload="if(media!='all')media='all'">
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"></noscript>
```